# How to print the values from a list based on indexes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have data in the list namely, **row** and I have a list of indexes namely, **indexes**

How to print that data based on index.

For ex.

```
rows = [['1', 'John', '20'],
        ['2', 'Mary', '19'], 
        ['3', 'Alex', '20'], 
        ['4', 'Jaydeep', '24'], 
        ['5', 'Meet', '23'], 
        ['6', 'Parth', '25']
       ]
```

and

`indexes = [0,1]`

Then I want to print

```
for row in rows:
    print(row[0], row[1])
```

Comment: Do you want to print the row value of that index or just the text print row[0], row[1], row[2] ?

Comment: this is a very confusing question..

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(*indexes)(row)` perhaps.  If your data was in a `numpy` array, you could directly use `indexes` as an index, but that's a rather major change for just this feature.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: @liquiddeath I want to print the row values of that indexes

Comment: check balderman's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like the below (as far as I understand the question..)

```
row = [7,12,90]
indexs = [2,0,1]
for i in indexs:
  print(row[i])
```

output

```
90
7
12
```

Comment: but... no one understands the question, i think

Comment: Lets wait and see  what the OP is really looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

The question is confusing. if you are looking for the array value, use  balderman's answer. from your question, it is understandable that you need to display "print". in that case use below code.

```
row=[1,2,3,4]
indexes=[0,1,2,3]
res="print "
for i in indexes:
    res+=" row[{0}],".format(i)
print(res)
```